# How to draw on top of a layout

Tags: android

I am new to android.

Can anyone help me with this problem.

I have a layout in which I have a imageView. What I want is I want to draw a rectangle on top of this image. The height of the rectangle is obtained during runtime.

I have tried drawing the rectangle by using shapeDrawable class and onDraw() method. But everytime I draw my layout disappears and what I get is a rectangle in a black background.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) to overlap views. In your layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/my_shape"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And then in `res/drawable/my_shape.xml` you can have a [Shape Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape), for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#ffff0000"/>
</shape>
```

A second option is to use a custom view instead of the overlay view and override its `onDraw` method to do custom `Canvas` drawing. In that case you would still use the `FrameLayout` to position the view over your ImageView.

A third option is to use a custom view and draw your image into it using `drawBitmap` calls in the `onDraw` method. This is probably the most flexible of the three methods.